# Django: how do i create a model dynamically

Tags: django, csv, django-models

How do I create a model dynamically upon uploading a csv file? I have done the part where it can read the csv file.

Comment: Why such things are needed? Please elaborate more, information is very short to know the exact requirement.

Comment: I'm trying to create a web application where different kind of users can upload their own csv files for anomaly detection. and then shape the model based on the csv file the user uploads

Comment: Then use NoSQL, MongoDB etc. That will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This doc](https://dynamic-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) explains very well how to dynamically create models at runtime in django. It also links to an example of doing so.

However, as you will see after looking at the document, it is quite complex and cumbersome to do this. I would not recommend doing this and believe it is quite likely you can determine a model ahead of time that is flexible enough to handle the CSV. This would be much better practice since dynamically changing the schema of your database as your application is running is a recipe for a ton of bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to create new schema's on the fly based on fields in the those in a CSV.  While thats a valid use case and could be the absolute right call.  I doubt it though - it lends itself to a data model for a single tenet SaaS application that could have goofy performance and migration issues.

I'd try using Mongo/ some other NoSQL solutions as others have mentioned.  But a simpler approach may be a modified Star Schema implemented in SQL.  In this case you create a dimensions tables that stores each header, then create an instance of each data element that has a foreign key to dimension and records the value of that dimension.

If you read the csv the psuedo code would look something like this:

```
for row in DictReader(file):
   for k in row.keys():
       try:
          dim = Dimension.objects.get(name=k)
       except:
          dim = Dimension(name=k)
          dim.save()
       DimensionRecord(dimension=dim, value=row[k]
```

Obviously you could better handle reading the headers and error trapping if dimensions already exist, but this would be an example of how you could dynamically load variable headered CSV's into a SQL db.