# How to create Django model from MySQL table on-fly?

Tags: mysql, django, model, field, mvc.jquery.datatables

I have a DB with tables created on the fly.

*(via the 'pandas' module: `ds.to_mysql ('BACTH_INPUT_XXX')`
I plan to use a dynamic model to display tables using 'django-datatables-views'.)*

How to create a Django model on the fly?

I find:

```
def create_batch_input_model(batch_id):
    name = "BatchInput{}".format(batch_id)
    fields = {
        'first_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
        'last_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    }

    model = create_model(name, fields, app_label='dynamic', module='core.batchs',)

    return model
```

How to populate model fields from MySQL table?

Comment: `python manage.py inspectdb` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: how do i create a model dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274601/django-how-do-i-create-a-model-dynamically) also take a look to [django-dynamic-models](https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-model/)

Comment: > """ inspectdb """ 
- how to create model without restart Django instance ?

Comment: > """ Possible duplicate of Django: how do i create a model dynamically also take a look to django-dynamic-models  """
I look both. How to create from(!) existent table ?